# Else em PHP para chamar menu conforme URL

Tags: php

Não manjo muito de PHP.
Eu tenho uma parte do site que contém um `<a>` com o caminho atual de onde o cliente está.

Esse é o código:

```html
<a href="
<?php if(preg_match("/segmentos/i", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))echo '/segmentos/neomot-'.$url[0]; ?>
<?php if(preg_match('/elevadores\/atuacao/i',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) echo '/atuacao'; else echo '/produtos';?>">
<?php if(preg_match('/elevadores\/atuacao/i',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) echo 'Atua&ccedil;&atilde;o'; else echo 'Produtos';?>
</a>
```

O que acontece, ele vai verificar se o link está em `/elevadores/iluminacao` ele vai dar um `echo` com a url correta, se não for isso e for `iluminacao/produtos` ele fara o echo para `produtos` por exemplo, e se eu quiser colocar mais uma condição?
Tipo incluir **cases** também, das mesma forma que está em produtos.

Comment: Já não tem um exemplo de `else` logo aí na última linha?

Comment: É só incluir `; else echo 'Cases'`?

Comment: Sua pergunta está um pouco confusa. Em que caso você quer imprimir `cases`?

Comment: se o link for `/cases`, igual está a chamada em `/produtos`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você quer usar case o melhor é gravar em uma variável a parte final da URL e testá-la com [switch](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.switch.php). Para isso utiliza-se a função [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.parse-url.php):

```
<?php 
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // http://seusite.com/path
$parse_url = parse_url($url); // pega as infos do url
$path = $parse_url['path']; // pega a path 
$host = $parse_url['path']; // seusite.com só pra facilitar na hora do href
$scheme = $parse_url['scheme']; // http ou https?
$href = ''; //variável que vai conter o href dos links
$anchor = '';//variável que vai conter o anchor text dos links
switch ($path) {
    case '/segmentos/i':
        $href = $scheme . '://' . $host . '/segmentos/neomot-' . $url[0];
        $anchor = 'Produtos';
        break;
    case '/elevadores/atuacao/i':
        $href = $scheme . '://' . $host . '/atuacao';
        $anchor = 'Atua&ccedil;&atilde;o';
        break;
    default:
        $href = $scheme . '://' . $host . '/produtos';
        $anchor = 'Produtos';
        break;
}?>
<a href="<?php echo $href;?>"><?php echo $anchor;?></a>
```